# Run excel macro on data refreshed cell change

Tags: excel, vba

Cell X5 =IF(J5>1,1,0)  I need to run macro when X5 is auto changed to 1 by data refresh of J5 ,NOT MANUAL INPUT! (tried everything,nothing seams to work,just dont get it)

Comment: include in your post what you've tried and what didn't work. if you have errors include it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Sheet1 make the following code in the Sheet1 worksheet:

```
Dim X5 As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("X5").Value = 1 And X5 <> 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Macro")
    End If
    X5 = Range("X5").Value
End Sub
```

We check to see if the new value is 1 and the old value is not 1 and then run the macro and finally store the new value as the old value.  If you want it to ONLY happen when J5 is edited then do this:

```
Dim X5 As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$J$5" Then
        If Range("X5").Value = 1 And X5 <> 1 Then
            MsgBox ("Macro")
        End If
        X5 = Range("X5").Value
    End If
End Sub
```